# substituting a string with a variable string

Tags: string, awk, sed, substitution

I have two directories, S and T, each with 150 files. The filenames are identical, so for example if S contains file1, file2,...,file150, then T also contains file1, file2,...,file150.
Each file in S contains exactly this code:

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a>  &rarr; <a href="page1.php">Page 1</a> 
&rarr;  NAME1  <a href="A.php"> &rarr Previous</a> <a href="B.php">Next  &rarr </a>
```

where all is identical in all 150 files except for NAME1, that is NAME2 for file2, NAME3 for file3, etc.

Each file in T contains exactly this code:

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a>  &rarr; <a href="page1.php">Page 1</a> 
&rarr;  STRING1  <a href="X1.php"> &rarr Previous</a> <a href="Y1.php">Next  &rarr </a>
```

where STRING1 for file1, STRING2 for file2, etc. are (fairly long) strings of other code that changes for each file, and X1, Y1 are also different for each file, being X2, Y2 for file2, X3, Y3 for file3, etc.

I would like to write a shell script that substitutes the strings X1, Y1 found in T/file1 for the strings A,B in S/file1, X2,Y2 found in T/file2 for the strings A,B in S/file2, and so on. I am working with either Terminal on a Mac or on a Ubuntu computer. I have done search online and on this forum and tried with both sed and awk but I could not get anything to work right. 
Thanks for any help or suggestions.

I will give an example with just two files instead of 150.
Suppose I had the script ready to go. Before I execute the script, directory S has file file1 with content

```
N1 A B
```

and file file2 with content

```
N2 A B
```

while directory T has file file1 with content

```
S1 X1 Y1
```

and file file2 with content

```
S2 X2 Y2
```

After I execute the script, S has file file1 with content

```
N1 X1 Y1
```

and file file2 with content

```
N2 X2 Y2
```

while directory T is unchanged.

I would like this to be done for all 150 files when I run the script.

Comment: If you come up with a [mcve] and post that you'll probably get more responses. See [ask]. Right now you're talking about a lot of files in different directories, with multiple moving parts in each, and examples with a bunch of complicated-looking text so YMMV.

Comment: From your question, why don't you just copy T and rename it S? The outputs appears to be identical then...

Comment: @Ed Morton thanks for the suggestion. I added an example in case there are only two files.

Comment: @Daemon Painter I had in fact made a mistake in describing the problem and your comment made me realize it. There is other code in the directory T that is different from directory S. I have now corrected the mistake.

Comment: What have you tried? (SO is not a code writing service!) BTW you have `STRING11` in your example instead of: `STRING1`

Comment: @user343894 Thanks, I have corrected the typo. I began trying awk: from directory T,
for $file in *; do  awk '/\<a\ href\=\"/,/\"\>/' "$file" > Sub/"$file" ; done
with the hope that this would extract the X1 string from file1, X2 string from file2, etc. and save all in a file in a different directory Sub as a first step, then I was planning to extract the Y1,Y2 in similar way, then use the extracted information to be put back in the files in directory S with some other script, but I got stuck at step 1, because I could not get awk to work, even though I had used it like that before.

Comment: Its very hard to see the difference between your input files and between an input and output files. Can't you post examples with text like `a b c` and `x y z` instead of `<a href="index.php">Home</a>  &rarr; <a href="page1.php">Page 1</a> 
&rarr;  NAME1  <a href="X1.php"> &rarr Previous</a> <a href="Y1.php">Next  &rarr </a>` and `<a href="index.php">Home</a>  &rarr; <a href="page1.php">Page 1</a> 
&rarr;  NAME2  <a href="X2.php"> &rarr Previous</a> <a href="Y2.php">Next  &rarr </a>`?

Comment: @Ed Morton  I have now simplified it as you suggested. One reason I had not simplified it that way is because the symbols N1, S1 etc are in my files really long strings of characters, with many special characters, and I was thinking that omitting that information may hide some of the difficulty of the problem.

Comment: If the problem is how to convert 1 file based on text in a second file than make that your example and include the complicated text in those 2 files. If the problem is how to convert multiple files then make that your example but with simple input files. Just create your example to best demonstrate which problem you want help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is probably simplest:

```
for path in S/*; do
    file="${path#*/}"
    awk '
        NR==FNR { $1=""; vals[NR]=$0; next }
        { print $1 vals[FNR] }
    ' "T/$file" "S/$file" > tmp &&
    mv tmp "S/$file"
done
```

For something as trivial as the last example you posted you don't need to use awk like that but from your original example it sounds like you have some more complicated processing to do so I showed where to fit an awk script into the process.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked like magic. In fact for me that's what it is because I understand little to none of it: would you be able to highlight the main steps it does? I am especially amazed by the fact that my original code was in fact a lot more complex than what I had posted even in the first example, but this script did exactly what I wanted. I would like to understand how it extracts exactly X1 and Y1 from the right places.

Comment: `NR==FNR` is a condition thats true when the first input file is read (see NR and FNR in the awk man page). All I'm doing is removing the first field (`$1`) from each line of the first file and saving the rest of the line in the `vals[]` array indexed by the line number. Then when reading the 2nd file I'm printing the first field from each line plus the `vals[line number]` content I had previously saved from the first file.

Comment: But if your question is really about how to extract specific fields from one file to use in another then THAT is the question you should post as that focus was obscured by the information about dealing with multiple different files in different directories.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Am I right in understanding that the script is able to locate "X1.php" because of  $1=""  ? and then it finds "Y1.php"? because of next ?
The reason why I included the information about having 150 files is because with only one it could just be done by hand and I wanted to explain why I needed a script. But I now realize that there are two different things involved, and I already knew how to do the second, so I should have asked only about the first.

Comment: The awk scrip I posted isn't intended to address the problem of copying your specific values from one file of your format to another, it's about how to operate on multiple files of the same name across directories. Please post a new question that's just about how to replace text in fileA with text from fileB and includes realistic contents of both files. Keep it clear, and simple and only about THAT, don't add all that extra irrelevant information about file this and file that in directory x and directory y, etc.